# regexp in javascript: find objects in string and get element from found objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, search, substring

I have find strings in input string and get substring from found strings:

I have input string:

```
<ipc:infoblock title = 'my title'>\
    <ipc:form:period        />\
    <ipc:form:time-scale    />\
    <ipc:form:hq            />\
    <ipc:form:regions       />\
    <ipc:form:apply         />\
</ipc:infoblock>\
```

I want to get a result in the form:

```
[{'<ipc:form:period         />', 'ipc:form:period'}, 
{{'<ipc:form:time-scale     />', 'ipc:form:time-scale'}, 
..., 
{'<ipc:form:apply           />', 'ipc:form:apply'}]
```

my javascript code:

```
var res = inputString.match(/<ipc:form:([^\s]+)\s+\/>/gi);
```

result:

```
0: "<ipc:form:period        />"
1: "<ipc:form:time-scale    />"
2: "<ipc:form:hq            />"
3: "<ipc:form:regions       />"
4: "<ipc:form:apply         />"
```

**but how to get the array described above, containing the results of the substring and elements substring (multidimensional array)?**

I do not want to use another search on the found strings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `/global/g` regular expressions will always discard capturing groups.

One thing you can try, if you have access to an ES2015 environment, is the sticky regexp flag:

```
const re = /(a)[bc]/y
'abac'.match(re) // => ["ab", "a"]
'abac'.match(re) // => ["ac", "a"]
'abac'.match(re) // => null
```

Otherwise, you're going to have to do the second searches on the result strings.